# Asp.net mvc 3 - view displaying required properties from viewModel which shouldn' t be

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am having a very weird problem

I have a viewModel:

```
public class ServiceView
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Titre de l' annonce")]
    public string NomService { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string DescriptionService { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Adresse")]
    public string AdresseService { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Le code postal")]
    public int CodePostalService { get; set; }

}
```

and a View which is tight to my ViewModel:

```
@model MeilleurPresta.Models.ViewModel.ServiceView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Déposer une offre";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div class="grid_23" id="body">

    <h3 style="padding-left: 50px"> Déposer une offre de Service </h3>

    <div style="margin-left: 50px">
        @using (Html.BeginForm()) {

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomService)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomService)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomService)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DescriptionService)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DescriptionService)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DescriptionService)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdresseService)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdresseService)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdresseService)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodePostalService)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodePostalService)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodePostalService)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Nothing special, however, when I submit the form, on client validation, it indicates me that the field: Le code postal is required, but it is not in the ViewModel.

I inspect the html source code, it generates the data-val-required class whereas in my ViewModel there are no require attributs.

Where the problems may come from ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your int isn't nullable, it's marked required by default.  You can either set the int to int? to make it nullable or you can add this to your application_start to change the default behavior...

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```